# How to check range of id's in Table material ui in cypress?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, autotest

I got this testing in Table Material ui React. And I have to check the values in each row?

```
<Table>
   <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
             <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
             <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
             <TableCell>Age</Table>
        </TableRow>
   </TableHead>
   <TableBody>
    {row.map((items, index) => (
        <TableRow key={index}> 
           <TableCell> {items.id} </TableCell>
           <TableCell> {items.customer} </TableCell>
           <TableCell> {items.age} </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    ))}
   </TableBody>
</Table>
```

One of my problem is I have to check if the customer_id that was search are range from 200 to 300, need to verify if all that was retrieve in the list dashboard filters only in that range.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the DOM after the values are rendered.

Comment: <tbody class="MuiTableBody-root">
    <tr class="MuiTableRow-root MuiTableRow-hover">
        <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-alignLeft MuiTableCell-sizeSmall" data-id="1">1</td>
        <td class="MuiTableCell-root MuiTableCell-body MuiTableCell-sizeSmall" data-id="1">Thomas Hilary</td>